# Is there a simple way to read all *.png files in ONE specific folder?

Tags: android, file, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have found plenty of ways to do that, none of them simple, though (and I wasn't able to implement the more complicated one, so I am looking for a simpler solution). I would like to fill my ArrayAdapter with the names of all png files in my direcory I use for saving some pngs from the app.
This one is great:http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/
but not exactly easy. I believe there is a simpler way, I just couldn't find it (and I really did my homework and was looking for it quite some time). I assume something like File.listFiles() could work, I just don't know how.

My code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    String[] values = new String[] ;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.diver));
}

@Override

protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    list.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.diver));
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    setContentView(R.layout.table);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.setInitialScale(50);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "DivePlanner" + File.separator + item);


}
```

I would need to fill values[] with the names of all the png files in the directory /sdcard/DivePlanner/. If anyone knows any easy way to do that, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

yes, you should use File.listFiles() method to get all the files from desired folder. When you have an array of files, you should simply iterate through it, and from each file retrieve its name.

if you want only .png files, examine java FileFilter class and its usage

for your conveninence, look here:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
final File directory = new File(path);
if(!directory.exists() || !directory.isDirectory()){
    //do something
}
final Collection<String> pngFilenames = new HashSet<String>();
for(final String filename : directory.list()){
    if(filename.endsWith(".png")){
        pngFilenames.add(filename);
    }
}
final String[] values = (String[])pngFilenames.toArray(new String[pngFilenames.size()]);
```